# Error importing html files as strings- unsupported extensions in typescript 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to import html files as strings in Visual Studio 2015 and am  using typescript 2.0.0. I created an ambient module declaration like this

```
/* import all html files as Strings */
 declare module "*.html" {
 var __html__: string;
 export default __html__;
   }
```

And in my imports

```
import DLATemplate from '/Template/activity/ActivityDla.html'
@Component({
    selector: 'activities-dla',
    template: DLATemplate
})
```

On building I get an error, tsc exited on code 2. On digging further in the build output details I get the detailed version of the error

***TS6054:Build:File 'C:/PMLBundled/Phoenix/Phoenix_LMS/Phoenix.Web/Template/activity/ActivityDla.html' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.***

Did I miss something. I do not want to change my html files to a .ts extension because I will lose my intellisense and syntax highlighting in the  html templates.